Determining the size of a circle moving at an unknown speed based on four intersection points at different times.
I'm making a coin slot receptor as a hobby project.
The hardware I'm making will have two sensors that will detect when the coin begins overlapping and when it leaves, giving me two intersection points with some time apart.
Here's a crude drawing.

With this setup I will get 4 data points.

t0 will be when the coin first overlaps point 1.
t1 will be when the coin first overlaps point 2.
t2 will be when the coin stops overlapping point 1.
t3 will be when the coin stops overlapping point 2.

This means I have three delta times as well as the relative position between point 1 and point 2. I also know the thing that intersects is a circle. The coins all have known sizes, but their speed is unknown.
What I'm thinking is I'll get somethings like this.

I feel like with this information I should be able to apply some sort of uniform scale to the delta times, until I have essentially four intersection points on a circle, giving me the exact size of the coin, without having to know it's speed.
Something like this:
I think I can brute force the math, but I'm wondering if there's an efficient way of calculating the size from the data points? It's possible to move the two sensors or switch to just one sensor, but I'm unsure if it's possible to reliably known the size with just one sensor and an unknown speed.
Here's an alternative setup that I suspect might be better, given the uniform shape of a circle, but I imagine I can transform the intersection times as needed, if I have to have them offset.


This is my first math question, please let me know what I can do to improve it or clarify.

@YvesDaoust, I changed it to be 1cm and 0.5cm.
